# Refresh Leaflet Js after get new data and add It into marker

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

i have loaded maps when document ready, but when i click some button, it will trigger new data and then add the data to the marker in maps, how can i achieve that

this is the initialize function

```
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
  } else {
    lokasi.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
   lokasi.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;  
  $('#Latitude').val(position.coords.latitude),
  $('#Longitude').val(position.coords.longitude)
   loadMap()
}

function loadMap() {
var lat = $('#Latitude').val()
var long = $('#Longitude').val()

    var mymap = L.map('viewDiv').setView([lat, long], 8);
    L.marker([lat, long], {
        icon: new L.DivIcon({
            className: 'my-div-icon',
            html: '<img class="my-div-image" src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/images/marker-icon.png"/>' +
              '<span class="my-div-span">' + $("#FullName").val() + '</span>'
            })
        })
       .addTo(mymap).bindPopup($("#FullName").val());

        L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
        maxZoom: 18,
        id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
        tileSize: 512,
        zoomOffset: -1,
        accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoiaGVuZHJhc2FwdXRyYSIsImEiOiJja2JhNm1tdGMwbDU4MnFwNWIweXI1bmh1In0.RZHAjY09Ji-M6B8Fnboemw'
    }).addTo(mymap);
}
```

this will load the maps to the current location, and i have some button, when i click the button, it will trigger get data from an array, and then i want insert in into map

heres the code

```
function addDetail() {
    //for load location from db
    var dataGrid = $("#GridDataAllWithPayroll").data('tGrid').data
    console.log(dataGrid)
    if (dataGrid != null || dataGrid.length > 0) {
        var data = $("#GridDataAllWithPayroll").data('tGrid').data;
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            L.marker([data[i].latitude, data[i].longitude], {
                icon: new L.DivIcon({
                    className: 'my-div-icon',
                    html: '<img class="my-div-image" src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/images/marker-icon.png"/>' +
              '<span class="my-div-span">' + data[i].name + '</span>'
                })
            })
            .bindPopup(data[i].name)
            .addTo(mymap);
        }
    }
}
```

how i can add the new data into maps, that will create a new marker from addDetail function

hope you understand my question

Comment: Is that not working? Do you have any error messages in your [console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console)? Check the [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope) of your `mymap` variable anyway.

Comment: if i hardcoded the data and run the forloop inside function addDetail along with the loaded page, it work

but the data doesnt come when page loaded, data comes when i click some button

i want combine the data with that function when i click some button

Comment: so its like the button click thisFunction()

and thisFunction will new add data to maps with addDetailfunction, i have try, but didnt work